# Is it possible to build socket connection between 2 iOS devices

Tags: ios, cocoaasyncsocket

Is it possible to build a socket connection between 2 iOS devices connected to the same network (Without net)?

if it's possible .. Is (CocoaAsyncSocket project) useful for me?

I just want to send a message from **Device A** to **Device B which put the app in background** .. when **Device B** receive the message should show notification to return the app to foreground.

It's not for the App Store, so I don't care if Apple would reject the app because of this behavior.

Comment: I'm looking at another question of yours ... for this problem, do you also want to make the connection over wifi, without access to the carrier's network?

Comment: I just want to use a local network like **ad-hoc** but without internet signal if possible ... thanks Nate for that quick response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you can do it, and **yes**, `CocoaAsyncSocket` would be useful. If you don't have to worry about the carrier network's firewalls and filters, then you should certainly be able to build a client-server app running on two iOS devices.  One opens the *server* socket to listen, and the other one (the *client*) connects, via the Wi-Fi network.

Trying searching on Google (e.g. `"CocoaAsyncSocket iPhone iOS site:stackoverflow.com"`) or directly here on Stack Overflow.

Here's [somebody who seems to have accomplished this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968548/cocoaasyncsocket-doesnt-work-after-being-in-background)

[Another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332084/starting-with-cocoaasyncsocket)

[And a post from Robbie Hanson himself, referring you to the EchoServer projects in the github repository](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cocoaasyncsocket/bijIRFMnOTE/exSx7d6SSp8J)

[EchoServer project](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/tree/master/RunLoop/Xcode/EchoServer)

You may have to use a **static** IP address for the *server* device (I'm not sure how much control you have over the Wi-Fi network's configuration), or use some other mechanism for letting the two devices discover each other.

Comment: Your words helped me ,I built a client-server app successfully as your advice , I used `GCDAsyncSocket`... but I faced another problem :(

Comment: the listener device couldn't read data received in background until it be foreground ... in other words It's delegate freeze's in background mode .. I want to read data received in background in order to show local notification contains (Show App) button XD ... do u have any idea to fix ? thank u

Comment: @Husam, I believe iOS shuts down sockets when your app goes to the background.  since you said this is not for the app store, [you could try this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6000223/119114).  basically, it has your app *pretend* to be a `voip` app, which would allow it to keep network connections even in the background.  I think you might need to add a *background task* to make this work ... see the link provided.  alternatively, if you are able to jailbreak the phone , then you could [build the app as a Launch Daemon](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/)

Comment: I found an easy solution ...I will install **Backgrounder**  from Cydia to keep the app alive in background .. Thanks, u made a huge favor for me.

Comment: @Husam, great.  I'm glad it worked out.  You certainly can do a lot of great things with an iPhone if it's jailbroken!