# Parse.com - Send message from Parse.com to iOS app, not like push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, chat

I'm developing new iOS app using Parse.com, which uses to chat between two users. What is my problem is, when User A sends message to User B, it will store in Parse.com custom class object. But I want to know, how the Parse.com let to know the User B about he received message from User A. We can fetch from User B app with some frequent time. But this is not feasible way.

So, Is there any option that parse.com will send message to specific user who received message recently? I don't want to user Push notification for this, because push notification is different concept and also not reliable.

Thanks,
Vijay.

Comment: This is one of the many intended uses of push notifications. You can send a silent push notification and have User B's app update itself accordingly.

Comment: APN (not sure if its and intended use of push) or polling (probably infeasible) or peer-to-peer socket (I've never tried it, but see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450597/is-it-possible-to-build-socket-connection-between-2-ios-devices)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is exactly what Push Notifications are for. Your only other option is polling for changes.

If you find Push Notifications unreliable you would need to implement a combination of push + polling.

There are some other technologies out there, but they're not options with Parse without a lot of middle-ware.